# Why reading attributes of an object makes the object undefine?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Below is my code, which gets data from Redux:

```
function ProductsDetail(props){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect( () => {
        const fetch = async () => {
            const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products/" + props.match.params.id);
            dispatch(
                {
                type: "product_detail_success",
                payload: data
            })
        }
        fetch();
        return () => {};
    }, [])

    const {product} = useSelector((state) => {
        return state.productDetails
    });

    console.log(product)
    //console.log(product.image)

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The `console.log(product)` line prints out:
[image]

However, if I don't comment out the following `console.log(product.image)` line, an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined` will occur.

`image` is just an attribute of `product` object , why printing it on the console makes the `product` object undefine?

Thanks in advence!

Comment: how about calling `console.log(product)` twice? Will the second call becomes undefined? Shouldn't be.

Comment: In the initial load product should be undefined, that's why you might be getting the error. Are you getting undefined In your console along with the current log?

Comment: @SujithPatil Ah... yes.. An `undefine` is also printed out along with the current log. Does that mean I tried to access the data before obtaining it from Redux?

Comment: You are right, the problem is just as you pointed out. Would you like to make it an answer? I will accept it. Thank you so much! @SujithPatil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initial render `product` is undefined so:

```
console.log(product) // will show nothing
//console.log(product.image)
```

when it re-render:

```
`console.log(product)` // This show what you see in you log
```

So try the following code:

```
console.log(product) // will show nothing
console.log(product?.image) // Add ? to make sure only get image when product defined
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, you are absolutely right. But @SujithPatil is the one who pointed it out first. So I will ask if he wants to make it an answer, if he doesn't, I will accept your answer. Thx again!

Comment: Right, Just want to add some explanation to help someone who's unclear about this.